# Invalidate cache when new question is posted

Tags: feature-request, caching

The `Newest` tab is cached for 2 minutes. This means that if a new question is posted, it may not appear for up to 2 minutes.

Is there a way to increase the cache time, but invalidate the cache immediately when a new question is posted? This way:

- Users get their answers faster
- People spamming F5 won't suddenly find 4 new questions they want to answer at the same time
- It's unlikely to be a performance problem for the server (even if a new question is posted every 20 seconds, generating 3 lists per minute is nothing)

Comment: In addition to your suggestions, I would like my brain implant updated in real-time, so I don't have to keep my cybernetic finger on the F5 key all the time.

Comment: so... you want to encourage people spamming F5??

Comment: Managing distributed caches is not as trivial as it may look on the surface (unless you're using things like memcached).

Comment: **Spamming F5?** Man, *"spam"* is applied to just about *everything* today. I'm going back to my self-imposed Monty Python marathon.