# How long does it take before new questions actually appear?

Tags: discussion, questions, caching

When I ask a new question it takes some time to get visible on the [[Questions]-->[Newest] tab on the main page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest).

Sometimes this delay is several minutes. Even some cases I see the new questions along with a nice answer from Jon Skeet when I refresh the page, that means all the users are not experiencing the delay similarly.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> does not eliminate this situation.

What is the reason for this delay? Can it be different for different users?

**Update:** This question took 1+ minutes :)

Comment: @BrockAdams no, question lists are cached ([see eg](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37456/invalidate-cache-when-new-question-is-posted)) but I don't have time right now to find a canonical meta qa

Comment: You probably have great many ignored tags and you choose to hide questions with those tags. The newest questions tab is not cached, I checked now and upon every refresh (every second) I see new questions. The homepage (active questions) is cached for one minute.

Comment: You see a nice answer from Jon Skeet because a) he's nice, and b) caches don't apply to Jon Skeet.

Comment: Jon Skeet actually has a time machine, that's how he is able to answer the question before it's even been asked.

Comment: @ Sha Wiz Dow Ard - You may see new questions in every second when you refresh the page. But it does not tell you that these questions are posted within last second. You see the light of the stars but that light is not emitted at the time you see the star :)